# Associative subarrays in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

How can the equivalent in PHP be done in JS?:

```
$this->gridColumnData[] = array('field' => 'id', 'width' => 50, 'title' => 'Enquiry Id') ;
$this->gridColumnData[] = array('field' => 'Name', 'width' => 90, 'title' => 'Name') ;
```

I know how to create a simple array like:

```
var myArray = [[23, 45, 12], ['stringA', 'stringB']] ;
```

But is it possible to do something like:

```
var myArray = ["numbers" => ["A" => 23, "B" => 45, "C" => 12], "strings" => ["firstone" => 'stringA', "secondone" => 'stringB']];
```

Comment: No it's not, but you could use an object -> `{key: {key2:value}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is an object literal, a container of heterogenous key-value pairs. In this case we'd have to combine that with arrays to get the behavior you're describing:

```
var myArray = {
    numbers: [{ A: 23, B: 45, C: 12 }],
    strings: { firstone: "stringA", secondone: "stringB" }
};
```

Ex. To access the `B` property in the object, you'd have to do `myArray.numbers[0].B`. To get the value of `"secondone"`, do `myArray.strings.secondone`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an object in JS:

```
var myObjArray = {
    numbers : { A : 23, B : 45, C : 12 }, 
    strings : {firstone : 'stringA', secondone : 'stringB'}
};
```

Access by:

```
myObjArray['numbers']['A'];
```